# Hover on div without moving other div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 12 div :

```
<div class="worktop_central">
   <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this css :

```
.worktop_central{
    position:relative; 
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.worktop_central .row{
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0;
  font-size: 12px\9; /* IE6-9 only hack */
}

.worktop_central .row div{
  border:1px solid #bfbfbf;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 216px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-top:20px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.worktop_central .row div:hover{
    height: 600px;
}

.worktop_central .row:after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

For example, on Mouseover of div "1", i would like that the div "5" and "9" down only and not 5, 6, 7, ... like on this example http://jsfiddle.net/ARNcs/.

Anyone have an idea how i can do that ?

Comment: What?... You only want one div to move down? Not all of them?

Comment: On your Fiddle it's 4,5,6 that goes down when hover on 1. Not 5,6,7 Could you be more clear about what you want ?

Comment: I want to move down all div witch under my mouseover div.
here au good example [link](http://fiverr.com/categories/video-animation#layout=auto&jls_ca20_auto=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd need to add columns to your markup.. to be able to group these divs properly.. I've modified your code in this fiddle:

[JSFiddle showing a possible solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ARNcs/1/)

After adding the columns you should give them this style:

```
.worktop_central .row .column {
    width: 216px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

And the selector for the inner divs should change to:

```
.worktop_central .row .column div{
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: It's a good idea, but i use bootstrap and i can't add a column. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add some kind of identifier (either manually or programmatically) to each of the divs, indicating which should expand.

This might be a class added to the divs you're targeting. If you know in advance which are to be expanded, you could even specify this with a data-attribute on the hovered div.

```
<div data-onhovermovedivs="5,9">1</div>
```

The key question is - how are you deciding which divs need to expand?

Comment: I want to move down all div witch under my mouseover div. here au good example : [link](http://fiverr.com/categories/video-animation#layout=auto&jls_ca20_auto=1)

Comment: Somehow you will need to calculate how many columns there will be.  Will it always be the same or will it change depending on screen / item width?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:left;` to the `.worktop_central .row div:`

```
.worktop_central .row div{
  border:1px solid #bfbfbf;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 216px;
  zoom: 1;
  float:left; /*This will do the magic*/
  *display: inline;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-top:20px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with simple jquery, for example:.

```
$('#a').mouseenter(function(){
$('#d, #c').animate({height:"600px"}, 400); 
});
$('#a').mouseleave(function(){
$('#d, #c').animate({height : "200px"}, 100); 
});
```

here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fafchook/LJWMx/
i rearenged your css a bit for this demo.
hope this helps..